# Sum the Digit in an integer

Tags: java

```
* Write a programe that reads an integer between 0 and 1000 and adds all the 
 * digits in the integer. For example, if an integer is 932 the sum of all its
 * digits is 14.
 */
package sumthedigitsinaninteger;

/**
 *
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumTheDigitsInAnInteger {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   

   System.out.print(" Enter a number between 0 and 1000 : ");

   int  num = input.nextInt();

   int extract = num % 10;

   int remove_extract = extract / 10 ;

   int answer = extract + remove_extract;

   System.out.print(" The sum of the digit is " + answer);

}    
}
```

I am so confused about this problem. I am reading a chapter in java book called Introduction to Java Programming 9th edition by Y.Daniel Liang. This chapter is a bout elementary programing which only teach me how to declare basic variable and do basic arithmetic. When I check online for help most of help I got with for loop or while loop which I have not read it yet. Anyone know how to do this problem without for loop or while loop because I have not get to that chapter yet. I know % means a reminder of division and / means quotient. when I did this problem manual I got right answer for 932 which is 14. I got it by doing a division twice  by 10 and add a reminder of those two division which was a 3 and 2 then I add a motioned a 9 to 3+2 which gave me a 14. I am so confused how convert a this logic into source code with my little knowledge of loops. Thanks.

Comment: You'll just have to proceed to that chapter with the while loop...

Comment: this sort of problems are usually going to be solved with a for/loop or with recursive calls to a method.

Comment: Since you know there won't be more than four digits to extract, you *could* do this without a loop, by repeating some of the code you already have.   But you should learn at least the basics of the language before asking here.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without any loops if you know that the maximum is `1000`.

This would work with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
    System.out.print(" Enter a number between 0 and 1000 : ");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    int ones = num % 10;

    int tens = (num / 10) % 10 ;

    int houndreds = (num / 100) % 10;

    int answer = ones + tens + houndreds;

    System.out.print(" The sum of the digit is " + answer);

}
```

This works because you know the number is *between* 0 and 1000. But as soon as you have learned about loops, you should go back to the problem again and try to solve it with loops, since that does not limit you to a given range for the input integer.

Comment: Let's hope that users understand that "Enter a number between 0 and 1000" means "less than 1000" ;-)

Comment: Well, yes ;) A good example for how important customer support is when it comes to large-scale products.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The number has (at most) three digits, right? 
The right-most digit is `number % 10`. The left two digits are then `twodigits = number / 10`, right? So, the next digit on the right, is then `twodigits % 10`, right?  And what's the left most digit? It's `twodigits / 10`! So:

```
int rightmost = num % 10;
int twodigits = num / 10;
int middle = twodigits % 10;
int leftmost = twodigits / 10;

int result = leftmost + middle + rightmost;
```

That's it!

You could do this with a loop too, as the comments suggest, but, since the problem you quoted limits the number to 1000, and because you seem to not know too much about loops yet, this seems more like what the author of the book you are reading had in mind for this problem.

Comment: Removing all comments, as they are meaningless now.

Answer (score 0):

try recursive methods ( hope u can understand this, cause its harder than for)

```
int digitSum(int number) {
  if (number<10) {
    return number;
  } else {
    int extract = number % 10;
    int remove_extract = number / 10 ;
    return extract + digitSum(remove_extract);
  }
}
```

Comment: 110% honest, asking someone who doesn't know about for loops or the fundamentals functions to understand a recursive function is like asking someone who knows how to solder to design a microchip.

Comment: why downvote? it was a way to solve it without for/loop.
it was actually the answer to question and i already explained it is harder than for ( maybe he is a smart student and finds out how it is working)

Comment: It doesn't fit the user's realm of knowledge and therefore isn't a correct answer for the question at hand.

Comment: I think this is a good solution because it allows to calculate the sum of a number's digits without loops. It perfectly fits to he questions criterias and is the most general solution. To understand loops you have to _know_ about them. But I think recursion can be understood if one understands how to call methods. I don't think that this comes after loops. And even if, it is more intuitive than loop syntax IMO

Comment: This is just creating a loop using the stack. If the user doesn't know about control structures then using an 'if' statement is just as foreign as 'while'.

Comment: changing the program in a way that Jvm handles loop instead of programmer is like asking someone who knows how to solder to solder a microchip into a board :P. ( it is still pretty hard, but maybe he is smart enough to find a way to do that)